# A question about using "not only .... but also"

Tags: sentence-construction, inversion

I was exercising on **inversion** in English. It came to my mind to write a sentence using the "not only, .... but also" pattern. I wrote:

> I believe not only does it work perfectly, but also it outperforms the previous devices.

After this I thought something is wrong with this sentence and I started to search about similar topics. I found this discussion on the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/not-only-but-also) website:

> *To add emphasis, we can use not only at the beginning of a clause. When we do this, we invert the subject and the verb:*
>
> *Not only did she forget my birthday, **but she also** didn’t even apologise for forgetting it*

---

My questions:

1. Is my sentence  grammatically and idiomatically acceptable?
2. Should I put the pronoun between ***but*** and ***also*** as what we can see in Cambridge's example?

Comment: Idiomatically, _it_ should come between _but_ and _also_ in your sentence. Grammatically speaking, too, I wouldn't dispute with Cambridge. The pattern is _Not only does [pronoun] ... but [pronoun] also..._

Comment: @P. E. Dant: I think OP has made a rod for his own back by using "inverted do-support" unnecessarily. Straightforward *I believe it **not only works** perfectly...* puts ***not only*** where it should be (immediately before the first verb ***work***, just as corresponding ***but also*** should come immediately before ***outperform***, being the actual "remarkable bonus". OP's structure simply doesn't have the right elements in the right places so they can be properly juxtaposed (because as you say, we expect ***also*** to be followed by the all-important *verb* here, not just a pronoun).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I see what you mean. However, I think part of the OP's approach to learning is to tinker, and so his purpose here may be to see what happens when he uses the inversion with _do._ That may be why it sounds slightly "off" to my native ear even with the "correct" pattern _but [pronoun] also [verb];_ my ear wants the verb to follow the pronoun. (This explains my ever so subtle "I wouldn't dispute with Cambridge" crack.) If I were composing this sentence I too would lead off with _it not only works._

Comment: @FumbleFingers You have adumbrated a more interesting answer here than I envisioned when I first looked at this.

Comment: @P. E. Dant: Well, with the basic structure *not only X but also Y*, it stands to reason X and Y must be *semantically* "compatible", insofar as whatever they refer to must be things capable of being "grouped together". But it seems to me that ideally we also like X and Y to be *syntactically* compatible, meaning that if we create a simple statement including X, we can directly replace X with Y and still have a valid sentence (apart from the proviso mentioned by Cambridge, that if *Not only* starts a sentence, we reverse the subject/object sequence)...

Comment: ...In OP's first example we can remove *I believe [that]* because it's just a syntactically irrelevant "lead-in" that can be tacked on the front of *any* statement. Thus when we "undo" the S/V reversal we end up with *X = it does work perfectly, Y = it outperforms the previous devices*. But since we know the true contrast is between ***work** [perfectly]* and ***outperforms** [previous devices]*, we don't really want the extraneous elements ***it does*** in X and ***it*** in Y. They're only there for syntactic reasons, but they interfere with the basic structure and semantics.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks, I wanted to write a pretentious sentence. What would happen if I go with the Cambridge example- putting the pronoun between "but" and also. I know you say that using extraneous *it* is redundant. Consider I want the sentence looks pretentious.

Comment: @Cardinal: P. E. Dant is quite right that idiomatically (in *most* contexts) we'd be expecting *but it **also outperforms***. That's because we tend to think it's more important to have the "syntactic marker" ***also*** as close as possible to the main *semantic* element ***outperforms***, rather than to keep the two parts of ***but also*** together. Whether to put the [pro]noun inside or after the ***but also*** element is a stylistic choice, not a grammatical rule. But here are at least two of us (plus Cambridge! :) who favour using the former option where possible.

Comment: Cardinal: I'm reasonably optimistic that someone who knows more than me about *formal* descriptive grammar will post a good answer here, but it's nice to know that at least *some* of what me and @P. E. Dant have said here may have been helpful. I'm sure all three of us are eagerly awaiting the next episode in this particular story.

Answer (score 1):

> 2. Should I put the pronoun between ***but*** and ***also*** as what we can see in Cambridge's example?

It's fine for *also* to come at the beginning of a sentence (or in your case, of a declarative clause that's coordinated to another with *and*), but in that case it's a sentence adverb, and should be set off with a comma (or, in speech, with intonation):

> […] but also, it outperforms the previous devices.

Personally, I find that just a tiny bit stilted in your sentence, but it's not unidiomatic (let alone ungrammatical). Rather, I think your sentence just flows a bit better if you move *also* to modify only the predicate, as you suggest based on the *Cambridge Dictionary* example:

> […] but it also outperforms the previous devices.

More generally, [Google Ngram Viewer shows that *but it also* is much more common than *but also it*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=but+also+it%2C+but+it+also&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbut%20also%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbut%20it%20also%3B%2Cc0).

Note, though, that this is only possible when it actually makes sense for *also* to modify just the predicate, e.g. because the subject in the second clause refers to the same person/thing/entity/whatever as the subject in the first clause. So in the following sentence, for example, you *can't* move the *also* after *weather*:

> Not only were the people very friendly and welcoming, but also, the weather was clear and warm and dry. So everything about the trip was just perfect.

This is because there's actually nothing special about the *also* in "not only […] but also"; you can also use "not only […] but" with "too", "as well", "so", "even", and various other words and expressions whose meanings are the same as, or subsume, that of "also". (In fact, it's not unheard of to use "not only […] but" without any such expression at all; but I wouldn't recommend that.)

(By the way, I should mention that although in these examples, the position of *also* determines whether it's modifying the whole sentence or just the predicate, the position of *also* does not always determine exactly what it modifies. For example, in a sentence like "She also works there", *also* could be modifying either "works there" or "she". So, don't overgeneralize from the above examples.)

---

> 1. Is my sentence grammatically and idiomatically acceptable?

Yes, except for the above. I'd also recommend adding a *that* after *I believe*, to make your sentence a bit more readable; "I believe not only" is a fairly intricate way to start a sentence. [Google Ngram Viewer finds that "I believe not only" is as common as "I believe that not only"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+believe+not+only%2CI+believe+that+not+only&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20believe%20not%20only%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20believe%20that%20not%20only%3B%2Cc0), *but* if you look at [the actual uses of "I believe not only" on Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+believe+not+only%22), you'll find that very few of them mean the same as "I believe that not only […]". So in sentences like yours, "I believe that not only" is presumably much more common.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Another question struck my mind: Can we use a phrase like the pronoun it- "......, but reading a great book is also helpful ..... ."